# When sever side adding new item that time how to load table view?

Tags: ios, swift

I can not figure out how can i do this
my i phone apps have a TableView . that is load by API .
it is working fine when application first time open
but problem is . when sever side adding new item that time my table not showing that .

how can i do that please help me

currently i done by this way :

NStimer use to 10 second interval re request
API to load TableView

```
timerStart = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(10, target: self, selector: #selector(OrderRequestTableViewController.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

**but i am sure it is not a good practice to use NSTime to request web api .. there have any alter native option**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one conceptual and effective solution for your problem.

When you adding any new item on server that time you can send push notification (Silent push notification) to devices to notify status that you added something on server side.

When device receives such push notifications then you have to call API and reload your table view. So you don't have to reload tableview every 10 sec.

Hope this might help you. :)

Thanks.

Comment: when server add new value then notify,
the apps,
then apps call api to retrieve data,
and reload table view.

Comment: Yes, When you get notification you have to call API and reload tableview.

Comment: ok that's sound is good but my api called view did load .. i am also using reusable cell that is load from nib(xib) file what should i do ?

Comment: You can call one method from which you can call API and when you receive notification you have to call this method so it will call your API and for nib cell will work fine you don't have to concern about that nib. just call API method when you receive push.

Comment: well fine .. but when application staying in background ? that time getting  notification

Comment: Then you can call API in background mode too and If you don't want that then another solution is you can call API when app comes in foreground or become active method of app delegate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129936/discussion-between-cristan-lika-and-ajay-gabani).

Answer (score 3):

**Normal Silent Notification is best solution for this**

It "will not show notification alert in notification bar, but it will only notify your app that there is some new data available, when you want to push new content.

Displayed in Notification center : No

Awake app to perform background task : Yes

just add below paylod from server side in push notification
{
    "content-available" : 1
}

```
{
"content-available" : 1
}
```