# Auto Refresh JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, swift, uitableview

So my app extracts JSON from a server that i don't control, and parses that JSON to populate a `UITableView`.

I want to update my `UITableView` to reflect the latest information available on the server in real time. So Whenever something changes on the server my UITableView also gets updated.

Now one solution that comes to mind is to Continuously send `GET` Requests lets say after one minute, parse the JSON and reload data on the table.

However there must be some other solution for this problem. I have tried searching but thus far no success.

Now i understand this questions is somewhat subjective by stackoverflow's standards but really i need help regarding this matter and i haven't got the slightest clue on where to start. So any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The simplest way is using timer. If the real-time is essential, use [socket](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift) instead of http connection.

Comment: You can refer my answer for solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41002245/3077339

Comment: But i don't want to use timer and the server is not in my control so i can't send push notifications

Comment: You could make an intermediate server that constantly polls the other server (that you cannot control) and then have the clients connect through sockets to your server.

Comment: My thought exactly @Caleb.  This is far superior to having an arbitrary number of clients polling.

Answer (score 3):

Repeated GETs are generally frowned upon, because it demands client and server resources when nothing is happening, which can be most of the time.

Since you don't control the server, **I'd recommend building a server that you *do* control that can perform the polling**, and then send the push upon detecting a change.  This has a couple advantages over polling from the client:  It scales better since only one source of polling will exist in the world, and it conserves client energy as well as the pure push approach does.

[Apple provides a push system (APNS)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1) wherein your server sends a message to your iOS device (via Apple). The device will launch your app in the background and invoke:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo;
```

on your app delegate.

Comment: Exactly i don't want to repeat GETs and the problem is that i don't own the server so i can't really send a message from the server

Comment: This would probably be optimal solution. Just take care to make a failover option in your app: if user didn't approve push notifications then you might want to pull the server at each app (you might want to do that anyhow) and then every 15' or so - if that makes sense... Depends on how people are using your app: do they start it and then stare at it for two hours? most of the times a refresh at each `applicationDidBecomeActive:` and optional "pull down to refresh" (since you are using UITableView this would be a 10-liner...) is more than enough...

Answer (score 0):

As the above answer states, its better to use APNS.
if however, you truly do not control the server, then as you describe theres nothing you can do except poll. Since you're writing for iOS, you're well advised to consider a few things:

- Wifi constraints: Are you fetching a tiny payload such that it doesn't matter whether you are on wifi? otherwise  you ought to configure reachability to not be a drag on the users cellular service.
- Backgrounding Sessions & background Execution: Consider using an NSBackgroundUrlSession to request this data. Backgrounding sessions are a bit more efficient to the OS in that they allow the OS to perform the request opportunistically.   Consider The Background Execution entitlement if You need to customize the NSURLSessionTasks for the background session.
- Scalability: can your backend handle continuous requests from your volume of users?
- better solutions might utilize APNS, or  Socket / WebSockets / Socket.io / firebase / etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Normal Silent Notification is best solution for this**

When you adding any new item on server that time you can send push notification (Silent push notification) to devices to notify status that you added something on server side.

When device receives such push notifications then you have to call API and reload your table view. So you don't have to reload tableview every 10 sec.

It "will not show notification alert in notification bar, but it will only notify your app that there is some new data available, when you want to push new content.

Displayed in Notification center : No

Awake app to perform background task : Yes

just add below paylod from server side in push notification
{
    "content-available" : 1
}

```
{
"content-available" : 1
}
```